# PIL and tkinter error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have this code, and the problem is I can't open the images. I did a random election to open a random image.
Thanks!

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import random
from PIL import Image
window=Tk()
window.geometry('500x550')
window.resizable(False, False)
f=tk.Frame()
f.config(bg='blue', height='500', width='500')
f.pack()
cat=tk.Button(window, text='Cat')
cat.config()
cat.pack(fill=X)
dog=tk.Button(window, text='Dog')
dog.config()
dog.pack(fill=X)
images=['cat1.jpg', 'cat2.jpg', 'cat3.jpg', 'cube1.jpg', 'cube2.jpg', 'cube3.jpg']
imgimport = open(random.sample(images, 1))
img = PIL.Image.open(imgimport)
img.show()
```

Comment: `random.sample` returns a list. you can use `random.sample(images, 1)[0]` to fix your issue.

Comment: @Axe319 Thanks, it worked! but now I have this error: ```UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 569: character maps to <undefined>```

Comment: Change this line `imgimport = open(random.sample(images, 1))` to `imgimport = open(random.sample(images, 1)[0], 'rb')`. You need to open up images with the `b` or binary flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.sample` is used to generate a list.
If you only want to get one,Why don't you just use `random.choice(images)`,it will return a random string from list `images`.

You used `Image.open` in the end,so there is no necessary to use `open`.

And your code in the last can be reduced to

```
images=['cat1.jpg', 'cat2.jpg', 'cat3.jpg', 'cube1.jpg', 'cube2.jpg', 'cube3.jpg']
img = Image.open(random.choice(images))
img.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

`random.sample()` returns a particular length list of items chosen from the sequence.
So even `random.sample(list, length=1)` returns a list, not the item.
You can use `random.sample()[0]` as @Axe also said.

Comment: Thanks, but now I have this error: ```UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 569: character maps to <undefined>```

Comment: @Axe319 said it again :)